# Docker image without using no-cache everytime you make changes in your git branch

Tags: git, docker, devops, docker-build

The problem here is whenever I try to create a docker image from the same branch in my Dockerfile, the docker itself tag the already built image with the new one using cache.

And without cache, it usually takes a lot of time.

What I have been doing to avoid this process is having a new branch every time which contains the new changes and then run `docker build`, which I think is definitely not a good practice.

I tried to find something for which I can use the cache but without using a few layers that I want to rebuild again, unfortunately, I couldn't find one.

Is there any other approach?

Comment: The overall procedure you describe sounds fine (both maintaining feature branches in source control and `docker build`ing images from them).  What specific problems are you having?  What have you done to improve cache utilization?  (You shouldn't ever need `docker build --no-cache`.)

Comment: @DavidMaze example - there is already an image in local which I build from a branch, now there is a change I did on the same branch. Docker didn't make any changes when I tried `docker build` for the new image and just used the previous image and add a new tag in the new image. 
Also, assume that I have a separate `RUN` statement in my Dockerfile which includes git clone and install all the required dependencies in one step.

Comment: You probably shouldn't `RUN git clone` in a Dockerfile, for exactly this reason.

Comment: @DavidMaze okay. Then, is there a better approach that I should use to create a new image with updated changes from the same branch without using `--no-cache`?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `git pull && docker build .` should work fine (again, assuming the Dockerfile doesn't try to run `git` operations itself).  Docker will reuse the cache from the previous build until it `COPY`s a file that has changed.

Comment: I tried that and it works great. Thanks a lot @DavidMaze